# Unable to print on network printer from WIFI connected device

Tags: wireless-networking, router, printing, printer

I have a small network with WIFI router.
My printer is connected to WIFI router via LAN cable. I can see in the admin page of WIFI router that printer is connected through DHCP with assigned IP address.

My all other devices are connected to WIFI router via WIFI connectivity.

Issue is that I am not able to print from the computers / laptops which are connected via WIFI. Even unable to ping the ip address of printer.

But when I am connecting my laptop to the WIFI router using LAN cable, I am able print the documents on the printer connected to the WIFI router using LAN cable. I also able to ping the ip address of the printer.

Again when I am reconnecting the same laptop  with WIFI to the router, then can't print the documents.

Kindly assist me and guide me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: What are the IP addresses of the printer, and of the PC - both when connected WiFi and via ethernet?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that could resolve this.

To give a better answer thought we would need more info such as make and model of the printer and the operating system you are using on your computer.

**Have you installed the printer drivers on your computer?**
a quick google search of the make and model of your printer followed by drivers will give you these.

**Does the printer have wireless capabilities?** Unplug the LAN adapter form the printer and set it up to run over wifi and see if it will print then.
Your router might not be setup to broadcast the printer by default.

A workaround could be, if you have a desktop computer that isn't moved, you can connect the printer to that machine, and share the printer across the network, which means any computer connected to your network can access the printer via this Machine.

**Heres a overview on how to do that**
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows/share-printer#1TC=windows-7